# TCL integer comparison

Tags: tcl

I wan to know how to confirm that two integers in tcl are close to each other?
In other words if the value difference between the two numbers is less or equal to 5, result is pass else FAIL.

can somebody tell me how to write it in tcl? or suggest me which operator i can use to achieve this.

Thanks,
Kallesh

Answer (score 1):

The difference between two numbers `a` and `b` is equal to `$a - $b`. This difference can be either negative or positive (or zero if they are equal), but to make the comparison easier you want the *absolute value* (magnitude) of the difference, i.e. the value disregarding sign. You get that by `abs($a - $b)`. The only thing that remains to do is to compare it with 5: `abs($a - $b) <= 5`.

The `expr` command can take this expression as an argument and calculate a truth value: `expr {abs($a - $b) <= 5}` will return either 1 if the comparison was calculated to be true, and 0 otherwise.

The `if` command can take this expression and use it for algorithmic flow control, i.e. to decide which commands get invoked and which get skipped:

```
if {abs($a - $b) <= 5} {
    # invoked if true
} else {
    # invoked if false
}
```

Re: Donal's comment; in my original answer I made the elementary mistake of pasting in an invocation of `expr` inside the condition to the `if` statement. There is no need to do that, since the first argument to `if` is implicitly evaluated as by the `expr` command anyway. It won't do any harm to invoke `expr` that way, but it will cause some snickering if someone sees it.

Documentation: [abs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm)

Comment: `if {[expr {...}] ...}`? Really?

Comment: Oh no. Peter Lewerin gets entangled in his own explanations, part XVII... In my defense, it was relatively early, and I had a hot date over last night (i.e. a good friend and her little dog).

Answer (score 0):

The `abs` function computes the magnitude of a number, i.e., if it is negative it negates it. All you have to to then is look at the magnitude of the difference between the two integers and see if that is within the threshold that you care about.

```
if {abs($a - $b) <= 5} {
    # Values are indeed "close enough"
}
```

This is a standard technique; it's *very* common when comparing floating point numbers (though a smaller “close enough” value is usually used; in that domain, it's usually called *ε* or epsilon).